# How do i preview a page in ionic?

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

I've followed the documentation for Ionic  and couldn't find the way to preview the pages existing into the pages folder.

Can someone explain the process?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer  in my case my app its running local, to see any page i must type http://localhost:8100/#/nameofmypage  and it will pop up.

Answer (score 0):

Type `ionic serve` in the terminal.